# Spring-data-mongodb DbRef Lazy with @Version cause org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Spring-boot 2.1.4,
Spring-Data-Mongo 2.1.6,
DuplicateKeyException when I load and re-save lazy loaded content.

```
@Document
public class User {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @Version
   private Long version;
   @DBRef(lazy = true)
   private Role role;
}

@Document
public class Role {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Version
    private Long version;  
}
User user = userRepository.findById("1234");
roleRepository.save(user.getRole()); //org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException
```

It works without lazy=true